# delete вызывает исключение

Tags: c++, исключения, delete

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
struct film {
    char name[150];
    char director[50];
    char genre[80];
    float rating;
    float price;
};
 
void show_info(film film);
void show_all(film arr[], int& length);
void surch_name(film arr[], int& length);
void surch_genre(film arr[], int& length);
void surch_director(film arr[], int& length);
film* most_rating_in_genre(film arr[], int& length);
film* append_film(film arr[], int& length);
void menu(film* arr, int& length);
 
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    film men_in_black = { "Men in black","Barry Sonnenfeld", "Advanture , Comedy",7.3f,8.9f };
    film star_wars_3 = { "Star Wars. Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith","George Lucas", "Fantasy, Adventure",7.5f,7.5f };
    film lord_of_the_rings_tfotr = { "Lord of the rings: The feelowship of the ring","Peter Jackson", "Advanture, Drama",8.8f,8.9f };
    film home_alone_1 = { "Home alone","Chris Columbus", "Comedy, Family",7.6f,10.9f };
    film it = { "It","Andy Muschietti","Horror",7.3f,6.9f };
    int length = 5;
    film* arr = new film[length]{
    men_in_black,
    star_wars_3,
    lord_of_the_rings_tfotr,
    home_alone_1,
    it };
    cout << "Добро пожаловать\n";
 
    menu(arr, length);
 
    return 0;
}
 
void show_info(film film) {
    cout << "Name - " << film.name << "\nDirector - " << film.director << "\nGenre - "
        << film.genre << "\nRating - " << film.rating << "\nPrice - " << film.price
        << "\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
}
 
void show_all(film arr[], int& length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        show_info(arr[i]);
    }
}
 
void surch_name(film arr[], int& length) {
 
    char* name_usr = new char[150];
    char* name_arr = new char[150];
    cout << "Введите имя фильма :";
    cin>> name_usr;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(arr[i].name, name_usr) != NULL) {
            show_info(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
 
void surch_genre(film arr[], int& length) {
    char genre[150];
    cout << "\nВведите имя режиссер : ";
    cin >> genre;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(arr[i].genre, genre) != NULL) {
            show_info(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
 
void surch_director(film arr[], int& length) {
    char director[150];
    cout << "\nВведите имя режиссер : ";
    cin >> director;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(arr[i].director, director)) {
            show_info(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
 
film* most_rating_in_genre(film arr[], int& length) {
    film* most_rating = nullptr;
    char genre[80];
    cout << "Введите жанр :";
    cin >> genre;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(arr[i].genre, genre) != NULL && arr[i].rating > most_rating->rating) {
            most_rating = &arr[i];
        }
    }
    return most_rating;
}
 
film* append_film(film arr[], int& length) {
    film* arr1 = new film[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = arr[i];
    }
 
    length++;
    film new_film;
    cout << "Введите название фильма : ";
    cin >> new_film.name;
    cout << "\nВведите имя режиссер : ";
    cin >> new_film.director;
    cout << "\nВведите название жанра : ";
    cin >> new_film.genre;
    cout << "\nВведите рейтинг фильма : ";
    cin >> new_film.rating;
    cout << "\nВведите цену фильма (m.q) : ";
    cin >> new_film.price;
    arr1[length] = new_film;
    cout << "\nФильм добавлен успешно";
    delete[] arr1;
    return arr1;
}
 
void menu(film* arr, int& length) {
    int choice;
    cout << "\n1.Показать все фильмы\n";
    cout << "2.Поиск фильма по имени\n";
    cout << "3.Поиск фильма по режисеру\n";
    cout << "4.Поиск фильма по жанру\n";
    cout << "5.Лучший фильм в жанре\n";
    cout << "6.Добавить фильм\n";
    cout << "0. Выйти\n\n";
    cout << "Введите пункт :";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        show_all(arr, length);
        break;
    case 2:
        system("cls");
        surch_name(arr, length);//dodelar
        break;
    case 3:
        system("cls");
        surch_director(arr, length);
        break;
    case 4:
        system("cls");
        surch_genre(arr, length);
        break;
    case 5:
        system("cls");
        show_info(*most_rating_in_genre(arr,
            length));
        break;
    case 6:
        system("cls");
        arr = append_film(arr, length); //error
        break;
    case 0:
 
        return;
    default:
 
        break;
    }
    menu(arr, length);
}
```

На 130 строке вызывается исключение.Я не понимаю,почему оно возникает

Comment: Укажите в вопросе саму строку и ошибку

Comment: а что за конструкция delete[] arr1? ссылка на ссылку?))

Comment: удаляете `delete[] arr1;`  и потом возвращаете  `return arr1;` ? Что? Надо было удалить старый массив: `delete[] arr;`

Comment: Да,там было delete[] arr просто,забыл исправить.Извиняюсь)

Comment: Ну очень смешно предлагать помогальщикам самим считать строки до 130-ти и гадать, на сколько мы обсчитаемся.

Comment: Я на самом деле другу помогал найти ошибку,потому что сам плохо разбирался в указателях.А отвечать через год на решенный вопрос тоже не очень смешно

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на эти строки

```
delete[] arr1;
return arr1
```

после удаления массива, Вы его возвращаете. Круто. Вот только указатель после удаления "невалидный". Скорее всего хотелось удалить arr (без 1)

Теперь осмотрим чуточку глобальнее

```
film* append_film(film arr[], int& length) {
    film* arr1 = new film[length + 1]; // выделили массив
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        arr1[i] = arr[i];
    }
 
    length++; // теперь length - размер массива arr1
    film new_film;
    /*[удалил, так как не важно]*/
    arr1[length] = new_film; // И запишем за пределы массива.
    cout << "\nФильм добавлен успешно";
    delete[] arr1;
    return arr1;
}
```

Явно увеличение length лишнее.

Может использовать вектор?

Comment: Без вектора надо

Comment: а почему? потому что в условии написано "динамический массив"? std::vector и есть самый что ни на есть "динамический массив. Но если уж так сильно-сильно-сильно хочется, заверните свой массив и  его размер в одну структуру (даже не класс). В конце концов Вы конечно изобретете вектор, но свой код упростите в десятки раз

Answer (score 0):

Выделили `length+1` элемент. Т.е. последний - с индексом `length`.

```
film* arr1 = new film[length + 1];
```

Увеличили. Теперь последний с индексом `length-1`:

```
length++;

arr1[length] = new_film;
```

И куда вы пишете? За пределы массива. Как минимум, UB — все, что угодно...

```
delete[] arr1;
return arr1;
```

Ну, а уж это вообще ни в какие ворота — вернуть указатель на освобожденную память. Зачем?..

Comment: delete[] arr было.просто,когда я пытался исправить,то забыл единичку убрать